# Python Boto3 Get Parameters from SSM by Path using NextToken

Tags: python, boto3, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I've been working with boto3 for a while in order to gather some values from the Parameter Store SSM, this is the code I use, which is very simple:

```
def get_raw_parameters_group_by_namespace(namespace_path):
    raw_params_response = None

    try:
        if not namespace_path:
            raise Exception('Namespace path should be specified to get data')
        raw_params_response = ssm_ps.get_parameters_by_path(Path = namespace_path)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception('An error ocurred while trying to get parameters group: ' + str(e))

    return raw_params_response
```

I used to have around 7 to 10 parameters in SSM and that method worked fine, however, we needed the add some additional parameters these days and the number of them increased to 14, so I tried adding a property in the boto3 ssm method called "MaxResults" and set it to 50:

```
ssm_ps.get_parameters_by_path(Path = namespace_path, MaxResults = 50)
```

but I get the following:

```
"error": "An error ocurred while trying to get parameters group: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetParametersByPath operation: 1 validation error detected: Value '50' at 'maxResults' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have value less than or equal to 10."
```

After talking with the team, increasing the quota in the account is not an option, so I wonder to know if probably using the `"NextToken"` property would be a good option.

I am not sure on how this can be used, I have searched for examples, but I could not find something useful. Does anyone know how to use NextToken please? Or an example on how is it supposed to work?

I tried something like:

```
raw_params_response = ssm_ps.get_parameters_by_path(Path = namespace_path, NextToken = 'Token')
```

But I am not sure on the usage of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest using this library (I'm the author): [AWStanding](https://github.com/jiss2891/awstanding)

You can achieve this easily, without worrying about pagination:

```py
import os
from awstanding.parameter_store import load_path

load_path('/stripe', '/spotify')
STRIPE_PRICE = os.environ.get('STRIPE_PRICE', 'fallback_value')
STRIPE_WEBHOOK = os.environ.get('STRIPE_WEBHOOK', 'fallback_value')
SPOTIFY_API_KEY = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_API_KEY', 'fallback_value')

print(f'price: {STRIPE_PRICE}, webhook: {STRIPE_WEBHOOK}, spotify: {SPOTIFY_API_KEY}')

>>> price: price_1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, webhook: fallback_value, spotify: fallback_value
```

Answer (score 4):

I remember running into this at some point.

You want to use a paginator - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Paginator.GetParametersByPath

This is how I used it:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ssm',region_name='eu-central-1')

paginator = client.get_paginator('get_parameters_by_path')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    Path='/some/path'
)

parameters=[]

for page in response_iterator:
    for entry in page['Parameters']:
        parameters.append(entry)
```

And you would get a list like `[{"Name": "/some/path/param, "Value": "something"}]` in parameters with all the parameters under the path.

*edit: response would be much richer than just the Name, Value keys. check the paginator docs!